503 failed to connect to all addresses -Google Analytics API
I have developed python script that google analytics report access via API. I added the libraries I use.
from google.analytics.data import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import DateRange, Dimension, Metric, RunReportRequest, Filter, FilterExpression
from google.oauth2 import service_account

Code give this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\PythonProjects\GoogleAnalytics\Venv_GoogleAnalytics\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 76, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "H:\PythonProjects\GoogleAnalytics\Venv_GoogleAnalytics\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 1181, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "H:\PythonProjects\GoogleAnalytics\Venv_GoogleAnalytics\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 1006, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:: Ssl handshake failed (TSI_PROTOCOL_FAILURE): SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED"
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {grpc_message:"failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:: Ssl handshake failed (TSI_PROTOCOL_FAILURE): SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED", grpc_status:14, created_time:"2024-10-14T12:52:05.1830382+00:00"}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\PythonProjects\GoogleAnalytics\GAPYTHON\deneme.py", line 106, in <module>
    main()
  File "H:\PythonProjects\GoogleAnalytics\GAPYTHON\deneme.py", line 97, in main
    response = get_report(analytics)
  File "H:\PythonProjects\GoogleAnalytics\GAPYTHON\deneme.py", line 48, in get_report
    response = analytics.run_report(request)
  File "H:\PythonProjects\GoogleAnalytics\Venv_GoogleAnalytics\lib\site-packages\google\analytics\data_v1beta\services\beta_analytics_data\client.py", line 784, in run_report
    response = rpc(
  File "H:\PythonProjects\GoogleAnalytics\Venv_GoogleAnalytics\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 131, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "H:\PythonProjects\GoogleAnalytics\Venv_GoogleAnalytics\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\timeout.py", line 120, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "H:\PythonProjects\GoogleAnalytics\Venv_GoogleAnalytics\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 78, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4: Ssl handshake failed (TSI_PROTOCOL_FAILURE): SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED


I controlled firewall and proxy settings but there are not problem. I update and upgrade certificate library. How can I solve this problem ?

Does that code really give you that error? What's the full traceback to the error?

I added full traceback

"E0000 00:00:1728910323.816962   13132 http_proxy_mapper.cc:135] 'https' scheme not supported in proxy URI" suggests you have an unsupported HTTPS proxy set up.

I use this proxy format -> os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = "https://user:password@ıp:port"

do you have an HTTPS proxy? The error is literally complaining about the HTTPS, not HTTP...
